# How to use roman numbering for PoemTitle?

Tags: roman-numerals, poetry, roman

with the memoir class, I need to display number poems using a roman numbering.
For example \PoemTitle{My first poem} give me this:

```
      1
My first poem
```

...when I want...

```
      I
My first poem
```

I there possible to change this default behavior, with something like :

```
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}{\Roman{poemtitle}}
```

But this line doesn't work for me... ?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside,french,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% \\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}{\Roman{poemtitle}}
\begin{document}


\PoemTitle{Signal\vspace{2cm}
}
\begin{verse}
Soleil : de cuivre

Dérivant dans l'épaisseur des maisons.

~

Un cri

Lancé vers l'aube inaccessible.

~

Et toujours le même silence

Piétiné par les chevaux guerriers.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Best,
Thibaud.

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you wanted if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing. Currently we have to guess what document class and packages you are using, so it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\thepoem}{\Roman{poem}}` in your preamble.

Comment: I posted a minimal example above for @Andrew. Thanks @Bernard; this works perfectly !

Comment: Preferably, don't use Computer Modern for a poem!

Comment: What font do you suggest ? By the way, I'm trying to reduce the line spacing for the content of the poem ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so Bernard had the good answer :

> \renewcommand*{\thepoem}{\Roman{poem}}

In the preamble works perfectly. Thanks !